# AMD Driver for Radeon HD8570 SFF graphics card on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, radeon, fglrx

Good morning all,

I am trying to install a Radeon HD8570 2GB grapics card on my Optiplex 7020 SFF desktop.
I've tried all permutations and combinations (AMD site and other third party drivers) and so far no luck. Can you please help which driver I need to download and proceed further?
My problem is: If I plugin the DVI or HDMI cable to the ports on graphics card the monitor goes blank. When I plugin the cable to original port on desktop it resumes again. The fan is spinning on the GPU.

Here are some additional details:

**1. My system:**
something@anything:~/Downloads/fglrx-15.302$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

**2. The drivers in my downloads folder:**
something@anything:~/Downloads$ ls -altr
total 181084
-rw-rw-r--  1 something something     14612 May 12 18:55 amdgpu-install_5.4.50405-1_all.deb
-rw-rw-r--  1 something something 185391473 May 12 21:53 radeon-crimson-15.12-15.302-151217a-297685e.zip
drwxr-xr-x  4 something something      4096 May 12 22:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 something something      4096 May 12 22:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 something something      4096 May 13 11:49 fglrx-15.302

**3. The output of AMD driver's presence is:**
something@anything:~/Downloads$ sudo lspci | grep AMD
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM] (rev 87)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]

**4. The list of drivers on my system after my experiments:**
something@anything:~/Downloads$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 87
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
resources: irq:29 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c40000-f7c5ffff
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:28 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

**5. Some of the commands that I executed are:**
something@anything:~/Downloads$ lsmod | grep radeon
radeon               1474560  1
ttm                   106496  2 amdgpu,radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
drm_kms_helper        184320  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
drm                   495616  9 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon,i915,ttm

**6. List of other commands**
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo chmod +x ./Downloads/fglrx-15.302/amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run

**7. Per this website https://idroot.us/install-amd-radeon-driver-ubuntu-20-04/ when I run this command below I can't download the apt file**

something@anything:~/Downloads$ wget https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-21.20-1271047-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz
--2023-05-13 12:47:48--  https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-21.20-1271047-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz
Resolving drivers.amd.com (drivers.amd.com)... 2600:1402:b800:792::b51, 2600:1402:b800:790::b51, 23.207.56.84
Connecting to drivers.amd.com (drivers.amd.com)|2600:1402:b800:792::b51|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/download-incomplete [following]
--2023-05-13 12:47:48--  https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/download-incomplete
Resolving [www.amd.com](http://www.amd.com) ([www.amd.com](http://www.amd.com))... 23.54.202.126
Connecting to [www.amd.com](http://www.amd.com) ([www.amd.com](http://www.amd.com))|23.54.202.126|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

Can you help here?

Thanks,
B

Comment: There is no way to install "fglrx-15.302" on 20.04. That driver has been depricated for years, and last worked on Ubuntu 15.04 or so. 20.04 uses a different driver called "radeon", which is autoloaded.